# I got Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: java, ms-access

When I connect to MS Access using Connection I am getting an exception that "Data source name not found and no default driver specified". My code is

```
   String dsn = "judydriver";
   String url = "jdbc:odbc:" + dsn;
    try {
       con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:judydriver", "", "");
    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("database connection: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
```

I created data source named"judydriver" in SYSTEMDNS. Did any  body to remove the exception

Answer (score 1):

You forget to specify driver. Do something like this:

```
String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
Class.forName(driver);
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:judydriver", "", "");
```

See [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/ConnecttoAccessDatabaseusingJDBCODBCbridge.htm) for more reference.

Comment: @srikanth: can you paste full stacktrace of exception?

Comment: @srikanth: Paste the stack trace in your question, not in Harry's answer!

Comment: @srikanth: try to run the program from the link in my answer if that runs then it means you are doing something wrong in your code. In that program don't forget to change url of database connection.