# connect to MS access from java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I tried to connect my java program to Access DB using jdbc-odbc bridge when I write my connection code this Exception is thrown and I could not solve the problem

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3073)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at jdbc.TestAccesDBCon.getConnection(TestAccesDBCon.java:44)
    at jdbc.TestAccesDBCon.main(TestAccesDBCon.java:21)
```

This is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
    ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
    System.out.println("resultSet MetaData column Count=" + numberOfColumns);
    st.close();
    conn.close();
  }

  private static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";  
    String connectionString = "jdbc:odbc:Driver= " +
"{Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=TestDB.accdb;DriverID=01";
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
  }
```

why this exception is thrown? please help?

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the generated exception .

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: What directory is your database in? You might want to try specifying the whole thing

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225300/i-got-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified

Comment: @dann.dev, in the root directory of my java project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you don't have installed the ODBC Access Driver (ODBC drivers are optional when Access is installed !), try to install drivers from Access installation media, if you are on a 64 bit system you should install the 64 bit version of the driver.

If you, going in ODBC Manager GUI in Amministrative Tools under the control panel, won't find under the sources tab the source :

```
Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)
```

this means that the driver are not installed on your system and you need to install it.

You can download Access 2010 driver from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255) .

Comment: may be, but how to install it,please help

Comment: From access installation media (generally an optical Disc ) or Download them from here : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: from data source(ODBC ), in the user DSN , the Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb) is found, but in system DSN it's not found
and when I try to configure it form user DSN and error msg appears say that the driver is not found, but how can install the driver?

Comment: See the link of the Microsoft Download page that i've posted.

Comment: it works now, but I should write the full path of db even if it is inside the directory of my java project, why?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String DBpath = "Your Database Path";
        String driver = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=";
        driver += DBpath.trim() + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true}";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(driver, "", "");
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(driver, "", "");
        return (Statement) s;
```

Comment: It works without writing this ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true:", I change nothing in my code except installing MS access driver and adding the full path of db. what I want to know why I should write the full path of db even if it's inside the java project directory?